# Issue with multipage in userform

Tags: vba, userform

is it possible to disable the multipage in userform so that users cannot click it? If yes, then how should the code be changed instead of putting `Me.MultiPage1.value = 1`? Also, I can't find the multipage name in the event list. How should I locate it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, individual pages can be disabled on a multi-page control. In your VBA somewhere, you need to identify the page(s) that need to be disabled and then set the enabled property to FALSE.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim pge As MSForms.Page

    For Each pge In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
        Debug.Print pge.Name
        If pge.Name = "Page3" Then
            pge.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next pge

End Sub
```

Doing this: `Me.MultiPage1.value = 1` will make the second page active (the value is zero-based, so when `value = 0`, this is the first page).

You cannot select a disabled page either using the form or with code.

The control name is shown here:

[image: Control Name 2]

[image: Control Name 1]

You can also disable the entire multipage control by doing this:

```
Me.MultiPage1.Enabled = False
```

Comment: You can hide the tabs completely with `MultiPage1.Style = fmTabStyleNone`

Comment: I have the next button for my form and I disabled the second page and put the code in, it still doesn't work